# Why doesn't NaCl work for electrolysis?

Tags: electrolysis, conductivity

So I found out online that to increase the conductivity of water for electrolysis, NaCl or NaOH is used.

However, upon using a low amount of NaCl in water and passing 12V through the solution, I noticed something weird, the cathode was bubbling a lot more than the anode (as expected in electrolysis - Hydrogen)  but after 20 mins, there was no collection of gas on the anode. Why could this be?

When repeating the experiment with NaOH, the desired result was obtained with hydrogen and oxygen on the cathode and anode respectively.

Comment: What was it that you expected, really?

Comment: Important info is missing: Electrode materials!

Comment: @Ivan Neretin I expect to see oxygen on the anode, which was not happening

Comment: @M. Farooq I used stainless steel

Comment: Steel could be reacting with chlorine. Did you see it corroded?

Comment: Yes the anode was a bit corroded

Comment: After running the setup for sometime with NaCl, the solution had turned a slight yellow

Comment: Oxygen? Why not chlorine?

Answer (score 3):

At the cathode, $\ce{H2O}$ is decomposed according to $$\ce{2 H2O + 2 e- -> H2 + 2 OH-}$$ So some $\ce{H2}$ gas is produced, and the solution becomes basic. At the anode, two reactions occur simultaneously and independently : $$\ce{2 Cl- -> Cl2 + 2e-}$$ $$\ce{Fe -> Fe^{2+} + 2 e-}$$ So the anode is corroded. Now the chlorine $\ce{Cl2}$ produced by the first reaction is a gas relatively soluble in water, which reacts with the ions $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ produced by the second reaction, according to :$$\ce{2 Fe^{2+} + Cl2 -> 2 Fe^{3+} + 2 Cl^-}$$ The ion $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ is usually hydrated in aqueous solution taking a orange-brown color due to the ion $\ce{[Fe(OH)]^{2+}}$ produced by the reaction $$\ce{Fe^{3+} + 2 H2O -> [Fe(OH)]^{2+} + H3O^+}$$ And the solution becomes brownish and acidic around the anode